# Почему в коде не работает margin-top, когда появилось меню?

Tags: html, css

Когда меню было обычным текстом, то свойство margin-top работало. Теперь, указывая любое значение для margin-top, ничего не меняется. В чём тут дело?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Piroll</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<style>
    header {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: 190px;
    }
.logo {
margin-top: 38px;
margin-left: 100px;

}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    color: black;

}
.text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.indent {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-indent: 610px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: right;
}
.menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightskyblue;
}
</style>
<header>
<img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
<div class="menu"> 
<a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none";
onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block";><p class="text indent">HOME</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">ABOUT</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">WORK</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">PROCESS</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">SERVICES</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p></a>
<a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none';
onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block";><p class="text">CONTACT</p></a>  
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем случае, `margin-top` надо указывать не для класса `text`, а для класса `menu`